# Change array value pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe:

Example df:

```
number  |  matricule<array>   | name<array>  |    
----------------------------------------------
AA      |  []                 |  [7]         |    
----------------------------------------------
AA      |  [9]                |  []         |     
----------------------------------------------
AA      |  [""]                |  [2]         |    
----------------------------------------------
AA      |  [2]                |  [""]      |
```

I would like to change the arrays when they have the value `string but is empty: [""] to []`
I tried by:

```
df = df.withColumn("matricule_2", F.when(F.col("matricule") == F.lit("[""]"), F.lit("[]")).otherwise(F.col("matricule")))
```

But I got an error:

```
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve, `matricule` = '[]')' due to data type mismatch: differing types.
```

Expected result:

```
number  |  matricule<array>   | name<array>  |    
----------------------------------------------
AA      |  []                 |  [7]         |    
----------------------------------------------
AA      |  [9]                |  []          |     
----------------------------------------------
AA      |  []                |  [2]          |    
----------------------------------------------
AA      |  [2]                |  []          |
```

Please someone can help me please ?
Thank you

Comment: Do you want to convert empty strings as nulls or remove them completely from the array?

Comment: @blackbishop remove them and keep an empty array []

Comment: If you are on Spark 2.4+, you can use [`array_remove`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_remove) like this : `df = df.withColumn("matricule_2", array_remove(col("matricule"), ""))`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe:

```
+------+---------+----+
|Number|Matricule|Name|
+------+---------+----+
|    AA|     [""]| [7]|
|    AA|      [9]|  []|
|    AA|     [""]| [2]|
|    AA|      [2]|[""]|
+------+---------+----+
```

**Filter out** "" from both columns:

```
df.withColumn("Matricule", F.expr("""filter(Matricule, x -> x!= '""')"""))\
  .withColumn("Name", F.expr("""filter(Name, x -> x!= '""')""")).show()


+------+---------+----+
|Number|Matricule|Name|
+------+---------+----+
|    AA|       []| [7]|
|    AA|      [9]|  []|
|    AA|       []| [2]|
|    AA|      [2]|  []|
+------+---------+----+
```

As stated in the comments, you can also use **array_remove:**

```
df.withColumn("Matricule", F.array_remove("Matricule", '""'))\
  .withColumn("Name", F.array_remove("Name", '""')).show()

+------+---------+----+
|Number|Matricule|Name|
+------+---------+----+
|    AA|       []| [7]|
|    AA|      [9]|  []|
|    AA|       []| [2]|
|    AA|      [2]|  []|
+------+---------+----+
```